# joomla 3 email to web interface solution - logging in, sending and receiving emails only through my joomla! 3 website

Tags: joomla

I'm developing a website and I was wondering if its fairly easy to set up an email interface with in my joomla! 3 website. An email system with inbox, outbox, possibly junk mail.. etc. I need basic tasks of an email system like Gmail or Yahoo, where the already logged in user at my website can send and receive emails with attachments only through my joomla website. Meaning the user can not use outlook or any kind of email application to send or receive emails. If the user needs to email someone with the email that we gave him after we registered him/her at our website, he needs to log in first to our website in order to have access to the email service.

I'm wondering if this kind of idea is easily achievable in joomla 3 as I'm kind of new to Joomla developing- only started a month ago. Or if it's too complicated and it costs a lot of over head. If it is possible how can I achieve it because I have researched the internet for 3 days with out any luck for a specific joomla 3 extension.

However I found other ideas like roundcube and squirrelmail but for sure I need something way simpler than that since the email service is already provided by my host. I just need an interface, thats all. Also I found this [link](https://netwinsite.com/dmail/autoacc.htm) that talks about something called DMail but also its too advanced and possibly a very old post too.

So please if any one could help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about for fun or for real? I think if you want to build something like that you need to do a lot of research. For example you should  understand how squirrelmail interacts with your host's exchange server. "Easily" is a relative term, but I think even for experts building such a think in Joomla Framework would not be an easy thing. What you might want to try is wrapping squirrel mail and integrating from there as much as you can safely do.

Comment: Hi Elin! Its for real. And ya I'm starting to think like you do. It's been a while since I researched this thing and no luck yet.

All what I found was a pretty old extension at JED which had really bad reviews. http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/ose-webmail-client-for-joomla

Anyways it seemed a really simple thing at the beginning. I just don't understand why wouldn't be a component for a joomla website that looks like outlook for example that you could integrate to your website. Its a simple as that!

I guess I will give it one more try and then forget about it.